# merging two pdfs in to single and attaching in the email in apex

Tags: salesforce, pdf-generation, visualforce, apex

I have a requirement where I want to merge two pdfs in to a single pdf and attach in the attachements to the custom object in salesforce then this merged pdf is sent via email.

Here is my code snippet. Where contentPdf is one pdf and b is another pdf content which needs to be merged.

```
    PageReference pdf = PageReference(/apex/FirstPDF?id='+ccId);
    Blob contentPdf = pdf.getContent();
    PageReference cadre = new PageReference('/apex/SecondPDF?id=' + ccId);
    Blob b = cadre.getContentPdf();
    String combinedPdf = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(contentPdf)+EncodingUtil.convertToHex(b);
    Blob horodatagePdf = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(combinedPdf);
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.Body = horodatagePdf;
    attachment.Name = String.valueOf('New pdf.pdf');
    attachment.ParentId = ccId;
    insert attachment;
```

But the problem is that it does not show the right documents merged instead it shows only one page in the final pdf saved in my machine. I have tried to use contentAsPdf() to retrieve content from pageReference but it does not work. Moreover the page is not well generated the one I get in the attachment. Or if there is any other way to do it quuickely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can merge PDF documents like that. It looks crazy. You can simply join text files together but anything more complex (JPEGs, PDFs...) has special structure... It's quite possible that your code works, in the sense that it generates a file which size is a sum of single files' sizes but it's not a valid document so only 1st part renders OK.

Try making another page which would just reuse the other 2 pages by calling them (use [`<apex:include>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_include.htm)). Check if it renders close to what you're after (there might be style clashes for example) and if it's any good - call `getContentAsPdf()` on that?

Comment: I achieve this task using some external libraries. In my scenario I was working  on lightning component so after merging them I downloaded it to the client system but in above scenario user can get back to controller. What's your thought?

Comment: Tricks like https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-merger-js? If you have a working sample by all means post your own answer! Lots of libraries out there but dev has to check if they play nice in Lightning Locker (or you have org-wide LWS enabled). There's absolutely value in client-side merge for example when pdf's over 6 MB big (apex heap size limit, actually more like 4.5MB useful because of base64 encoding you may need...). But if you need a visualforce email template for example - no javascript tricks, has to be VF. Or combine the document, upload as File, reference it in email? Bit "meh".